# Case insensitive search in jqGrid including hidden fields

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, field, hidden, case-insensitive

I have few hidden fields in my jqGrid on which I have to perform a case insensitive search (may be using regex - not sure). Is it possible? Can someone give me directions on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You should inseart [searchhidden](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) option equal to `true` in the column definition (`colModel`):

```
searchoptions:{searchhidden:true}
```

To make searching case insensitive you can use jQgrid option [ignoreCase:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions).