# jqgrid reload full data grid after search operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

when I do a search operation on my jqgrid it display me the correct response but, if I click on reload grid it display me always the same response of the search op.

How can I reload the entire data? I would use the default navgrid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Reload Grid" button of the navigation toolbar *clear the filter* and reload unfiltered grid contain. If you open the "Find Records" button of the navigation toolbar *the previous filter* should be displayed. Clicking on the "Find" button will follow to reloading the data *with the current filter*.

If you use both "Find Records" button of the navigation toolbar and the [Searching toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) in the same grid I would recommend you to use `recreateFilter: true` option of the searching dialog (see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875294/two-related-questions-on-jqgrid-column-header-filters-and-the-advanced-filtering/6884755#6884755)). In the case the current filters from the searching toolbar will be used in the searching dialog.

If the advises not solve your problem you should append your question with the code fragment which you use and describes more exactly the behavior which you would like to have.