# How to pass complex search criteria to jqgrid from query string

Tags: jqgrid

I tried code below to pass filter to url which invokes jqgrid. jqGrid still shows all rows, passed filter is not passed to url to retrieve data form server.
How to force jqGrid to filter by filter passed in query string ?

```
window.open( '/Grid?filters=' + encodeURIComponent(
  '{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Name","op":"cn","data":"John"}' ));
```

Comment: Is URL `/Grid` is the page which has `<table id="grid"></table>` or is it the server URL which returns JSON data filled in the grid?

Comment: @Oleg: Grid is ASP .NET MVC2 controller which returns page containing grid with id 'grid'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse `window.location.href` and get all parameters which you need. If the URL contains the parameter which you need you can decode it with respect of [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) and use like you as need.

The following code can be used for tests. It demonstrate how to decode `filters` parameter.

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') < 0) {
    // the code will open the current HTML page with additional
    // parameter "filters" and reopen the same page with the parameters
    window.location = window.location.href + '?' +
        $.param({
            filters: JSON.stringify({
                groupOp: "AND",
                rules: [
                    {field: "Name", op: "cn", data: "John Smith"}
                ]
            })
        });
} else {
    // decode URL parameters and place in the as properties in the
    // object "parameters":
    var namedParameters = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&'),
        parameters = {},
        nameAndValue,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < namedParameters.length; i += 1) {
        nameAndValue = namedParameters[i].split('=');
        parameters[nameAndValue[0]] = decodeURIComponent(nameAndValue[1]);
        if (nameAndValue[0] === "filters") {
            // display the data from the "filters" parameter
            var myFilters = $.parseJSON(decodeURIComponent(nameAndValue[1]));
            alert(myFilters.rules[0].data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I tried code but got exception that hashes is undefined. I replaced it with namedParameters

Comment: @Andrus: I made some modifications of the names during including the code fragment in the answer. The `hashes.length` should be renamed to `namedParameters.length`.

Comment: Thank you. if data value is space, e.q. `data:" "`,  plus character is passed to controller which gets json data instead of space.

Comment: Search criteria usually contains column names and values concatenated with AND like `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Name","op":"eq","data":"John"},{"field":"Company","op":"eq","data":"Soft"}]}`. How to pre-fill search toolbar from this data?

Comment: @Andrus: The encoded URL data having any special characters have to be decoded (see `decodeURIComponent` in my code for example). Depend on how you forward the information to the server the server do decoding automatically or you should decode the data manuals. For example you can use [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) in ASP.NET. On other your question I answered already. [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6884755/315935) describes how to fill searching toolbar with the data from `postData.filters`.