# how to add standard textbox command to jqgrid context menu

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, contextmenu

If context menu is added to jqGrid using [Custom values to Context Menu Items in JQgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451982/custom-values-to-context-menu-items-in-jqgrid) and text filed inline editing is used, textbox standard context menu is not available, it is replace with jqGrid context menu.

How to add standard textbox  context menu commands ( Undo, Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete, Select all ) to jqGrid conext menu or how to show standard context menu for textbox inline editing?

**Update**

On inline edit, if standard menu is opened by right clicking on yellow background or in autocomplete box and after that standard browser context menu is opened, custom menu is not closed, two menus appear.

[image: two menus]

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to implement in context menu commands like "Copy", "Paste", ... so I decide to modify my demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460116/315935) on your previous question. In [the new demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CreateContextmenuFromNavigatorButtons1.htm) the context menu appears only if the page contains no selected text.

The first problem is that the original code of the `jquery.contextmenu.js` contains the following code fragment:

```
$(this).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
  // Check if onContextMenu() defined
  var bShowContext = (!!hash[index].onContextMenu) ? hash[index].onContextMenu(e) : true;
  if (bShowContext) display(index, this, e, options);
  return false;
});
```

So the `contextmenu` handler return always `false` and prevent creating of the standard context menu. I fix the code to the following (you can download full modified code [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.2.0/plugins/jquery.contextmenu-fixed1.js)):

```
$(this).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
  // Check if onContextMenu() defined
  var bShowContext = (!!hash[index].onContextMenu) ? hash[index].onContextMenu(e) : true;
  currentTarget = e.target;
  if (bShowContext) {
    display(index, this, e, options);
    return false;
  }
});
```

The code of `createContexMenuFromNavigatorButtons` functions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460116/315935) I modified

```
onContextMenu: function (e) {
    var rowId = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"), p = grid[0].p, i,
        lastSelId;

    if (rowId && getSelectedText() === '') {
        ...
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; // no contex menu
    }
}
```

to use `getSelectedText()` and to create the context menu only if no text is selected. As the result you will be see your custom context menu only if no text is selected and see the standard context menu (which depend on web browser) if the text selection exist:

[image]

**UPDATED**: I modified my bug report about `jquery.contextmenu.js` with [additional information](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/small-bug-fixes-in-jquery-contextmenu-js-plugin/#p25365) based on the answer. I hope that the changes will be soon in the main code of `jquery.contextmenu.js` included in the `plugins` subdirectory.

**UPDATED 2**: How you can see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/8f4aecc2b53bc4f52bc9ea19d9ea068ce2abc205) all the fixes are already in the main code of jqGrid on the [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/) and in included in the jqGrid 4.3.

**UPDATED 3**: If you want to have the standard context menu for all *enabled* `<input type="text" ...>`, `<input type="textarea" ...>` and `<textarea ...>` elements you should just modify a little the code inside of `onContextMenu` callback. For example

```
onContextMenu: function (e) {
    var p = grid[0].p, i, lastSelId,
        $target = $(e.target),
        rowId = $target.closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"),
        isInput = $target.is(':text:enabled') ||
        $target.is('input[type=textarea]:enabled') ||
        $target.is('textarea:enabled');
    if (rowId && !isInput && getSelectedText() === '') {
        ...
```

see one more [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CreateContextmenuFromNavigatorButtons3.htm) where inline editing will be activate by double-click.

Comment: thank you very much. If text is not selected, paste and select all commands should be still available. How to add standard textbox context menu to the custom menu you created ? In this case both commands are available.

Comment: @Andrus: I think it's not possible.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to use solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript or others?

Comment: @Andrus: I seen the answer before, but the usage of Flash is not an option for me in the pure JavaScript solution. Moreover the standard context menu is absolutely different in different browsers.

Comment: Thank you. Copy command can implemented using javascript prompt as described. How about implementing select all, paste, delete commands? It looks like everything can implemented in javascript.

Comment: @Andrus: The accepted answer on the referenced question use Flash. I answered also on your another question before: "I think it's not possible".

Comment: Thank you. If text is selected in inline edit, standard menu does not appear. How to force standard menu to appear in selected text in inine edit ?

Comment: @Andrus: Do you probably mean `<input type="text" .../>`, `<input type="textarea" .../>` or `<textarea ...>` if you write about "inline edit". I posted you one more demo in the **UPDATED 3** part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. If standard menu is opened after custom one, custom menu remains open. I updated question. How to fix this ?