# Trouble making JqGrid footer static inside a container

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with a lot of columns, when I scroll the container on horizontal my buttons in the footer of the Jqgrid hide, I wish to make the footer Static so I could scroll and still be able to see the content of the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CreateContextmenuFromNavigatorButtons3.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460480/315935) (see also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460116/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491939/315935)). It shows how to generate **context menu** which contains the same information which you included in the navigator buttons. I personally you one from the modifications of the approach and find in very practical. The user *don't need to scroll* at all. The user need just click right mouse button to do the same action. It's very practical in case of long grids with many rows or grids with many columns like in your case.

Comment: thanks man , I think that should help , the user will no more have to scroll back to edit, delete or add a row .