# Jqgrid - How to retain the hovered style when using context menu for a row

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

In jqgrid when I hover the mouse on any row it highlights the row. But when I use context enu, the highlighted style is gone for that row.

Now users are not aware which row was the context menu opened for. I would like to know if we can retain the hovered style. I know we can do setSelect on the grid for the selected row, but I don't want to select the row. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) (or the [jQuery.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event which is the same) to set the `ui-state-hover` class on the row on which the context menu will be opened. In the way you can fix the behavior from the standard

[image]

to the following:

[image]

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/InlineEditingInContextmenu.htm) demonstrate my suggestion live. The corresponding code I included below:

```
$grid.contextMenu('myMenu1', {
    bindings: {
        edit: function (trigger, currentTarget) {
            $(trigger).jqGrid('editRow',
                $(currentTarget).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr('id'),
                true);
        },
        del: function (trigger, currentTarget) {
            $(trigger).jqGrid('delGridRow',
                $(currentTarget).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr('id'));
        }
    },
    menuStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fcfdfd',
        border: '1px solid #a6c9e2',
        maxWidth: '600px',
        width: '100%'
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
        border: '1px solid #79b7e7',
        color: '#1d5987',
        backgroundColor: '#d0e5f5'
    },
    onShowMenu: function (e, $menu) {
        var $row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
        $menu.mouseover(function () {
            try {
                $row.siblings().removeClass('ui-state-hover');
            } catch (e) {}
            $row.addClass('ui-state-hover');
        }).mouseleave(function (e) {
            var $rowNew = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
            if ($rowNew.attr('id') !== $row.attr('id')) {
                $row.removeClass('ui-state-hover');
            }
        });
        return $menu;
    }
});
```

Comment: Oleg: Just wondering if it is possible to close the context menu, on pressing ESC key?

Comment: @varaprakash: The implementation of contextmenu plugin from the plugins subfolder of jqGrid don't support any keyboard events. You can look as the menu which will be included in the next version of jQuery UI ([here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js)) to see how to use `keydown` with menu. The usage of ESC key is simple, but having one feature you will sure need support of another keys.