# jqGrid: Update advanced search dialog, column dropdown – after adding column with columnchooser

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have an issue with the advanced search of the jqGrid…. From what I get, the advanced search dialog box is only created once, when searchGrid is called.

This means that if I add a column via columnChooser after I already opened the advanced searchdialog once, the added column is missing the next time I open the advanced search dialog… I suppose this is the normal behaviour….

So my question is: Is there any standard function I can use to update/recreate the advanced search dialog everytime I call the searchGrid without loosing all the previously entered search criterias etc.?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can fix the problem by usage of `recreateFilter: true` option of searching dialog. You can set the option as default setting by usage

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {recreateFilter: true});
```

Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726334/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884755/315935) for details.