# multiple jqgrid on single page + search feature works only for last grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid

I am trying to show three jqGrid in single page.  all things works fine, but problem is when I am trying to use search functionality of jqGrid at that time it only searches from last grid only!

i have three different box for search in individual grid.

how can resolve this problem , anyone know plz help me out...

**Update:**
I have applied three different table ids as well as pager ids also.

Comment: Do the jqgrids have different ids (and not simply 'mygrid' as in the docs)?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you will be able to fix the problem by usage of `recreateFilter: true` option of searching. The simplest way to use it is changing of defaults:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {recreateFilter: true});
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726334/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884755/315935) for additional information.