# How can we indicate that a filter is applied on a Column header in a jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, grid

I want to add an indication to the default column header of the jqGrid whenever a filter is applied.

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25019875/315935). I hope it's what you need.