# jqGrid : retain the sorting, paging and filtertoolbar selection after new data has assigned to grid

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid, grid, paging

i have jqgrid with paging,sorting, filtertoolbar (with two dropdownlist) i am using signalR when any CRUD operation occurs on the data. Server send the refresh json and rebind it to the grid.

I want to retain the old sorting,paging and values in dropdownlist(in filtertoolbar) and inputfields as well (in filtertoolbar) after rebinding the fresh json to Grid() please help.

this is the code that i am using with it

```
function PopulateOrdersTable(CCOrder) {
    var gridPageNumber = 1;
    if ($(".ui-pg-input").val() != "1" && $(".ui-pg-input").val() != undefined) {
        gridPageNumber = $(".ui-pg-input").val();
    }

    var sortColumnName = $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname');
    var sortOrder = $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortorder');

    $('#jqgrid').jqGrid('GridUnload');

    if (CCOrder != null) {
        jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
            data: CCOrder,
            datatype: "local",
            height: 'auto',
            ignoreCase: true,
            stringResult: true,
            colNames: ['#', 'Driver', 'Customer', 'Order Time', 'Delivery Time', 'ETA (Min(s))', 'Amount (AED)', 'Status'],
            colModel: [{
                name: 'OrderId',
                index: 'OrderId',
                width: 50
            }, {
                name: 'DriverName',
                index: 'DriverName',
                width: 120,
                sorttype: "string"
            }, {
                name: 'CustomerName',
                index: 'CustomerName',
                width: 120,
                sorttype: "string"
            }, {
                name: 'StringOrderTime',
                index: 'StringOrderTime',
                sorttype: "date",
                width: 80,
                sopt: ['eq'],
            }, {
                name: 'StringDeliveryTime',
                index: 'StringDeliveryTime',
                sorttype: "date",
                width: 80,
                sorttype: "string",
                sopt: ['eq'],
            }, {
                name: 'StringCustomerETA',
                index: 'StringCustomerETA',
                sorttype: "number",
                width: 70,
                sopt: ['eq'],
            }, {
                name: 'OrderAmount',
                index: 'OrderAmount',
                width: 50,
                sorttype: "number",
                sopt: ['eq'],
            }, {
                name: 'OrderStatus',
                index: 'OrderStatus',
                width: 150,
                sorttype: "string"
            }],
            afterRefresh: function () { ("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true }); },
            rowNum: 5,
            //rowList: [5, 10, 15],
            pager: '#pjqgrid',
            sortname: 'CustomerETA',
            toolbarfilter: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            autowidth: true,
            onSelectRow: function (id) {

                var myGrid = $('#jqgrid'),
                    selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
                    celValue = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'OrderId');

                PopulateOneDriverOneOrder(celValue);
            }
        });

        setSearchSelect('OrderId', CCOrder);
        setSearchSelect('DriverName', CCOrder);
        setSearchSelect('CustomerName', CCOrder);

        setSearchSelect('OrderStatus', CCOrder);

        $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {  autosearch:true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
        //$("#jqGrid").setGridParam({datatype: 'json', url:'/get_data.php'});
        $("#jqgrid")[0].triggerToolbar();

        $(".ui-jqgrid").removeClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content");
        $(".ui-jqgrid-view").children().removeClass("ui-widget-header ui-state-default");
        $(".ui-jqgrid-labels, .ui-search-toolbar").children().removeClass("ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr");
        $(".ui-jqgrid-pager").removeClass("ui-state-default");
        $(".ui-jqgrid").removeClass("ui-widget-content");

        // add classes
        $(".ui-jqgrid-htable").addClass("table table-bordered table-hover");
        $(".ui-jqgrid-btable").addClass("table table-bordered table-striped");

        $(".ui-pg-div").removeClass().addClass("btn btn-sm btn-primary");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-plus").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-plus");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-pencil").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-pencil");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-trash").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-trash-o");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-search").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-search");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-refresh").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-refresh");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-disk").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-save").parent(".btn-primary").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-cancel").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-times").parent(".btn-primary").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");

        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-prev").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-prev").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-backward");

        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-first").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-first").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-fast-backward");

        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-forward");

        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-fast-forward");

        if (gridPageNumber != 1) {
            grid = $('#jqgrid')
            grid.setGridParam({
                page: gridPageNumber,
                sortname: sortColumnName,
                sortorder: sortOrder,
            });
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
        else
        {
            grid = $('#jqgrid')
            grid.setGridParam({
                sortname: sortColumnName,
                sortorder: sortOrder,
            });
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should include more details in your question. "rebinding" can be interpreted in many many different way. One have to see what you do to be able to help you. Probably the code from [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884755/315935) could help you, but I try just guess, because I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you do.

Comment: ok my data is refreshing on the grid as soon as it gets updated in the table in dbserver. then json is sent to client from server after that i rebind the new data to the grid. for example during this process if some one is filtering some record or any other things the filer get reset and the person has to filter it again i manage to save the pagenumber and sorting but still not able to save filteroptions

Comment: I used signalR too in combination with jqGrid, but you should understand that one can write a lot of different *implementations* of what you write. I'm afraid that nobody could help you if you just explain what you do instead of posting fragments of your code. Probably you could just call `triggerToolbar` after updating the data in jqGrid (if you correctly updated the data). I can compare your question with the following: "I have a program which do not what I want. Could you help me to fix the problem?" It's clear that your description is not so common, but it still have not enough details.

Comment: triggerToolbar works for me thanks for support

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. I would recommend you to look at [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) (read the readme and the [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) too). It contains a lot of enhancements. Especially support of [Font Awesome](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8) out of the box can be interesting for you. The code is published on all repositories and can be accessed from [CDNs](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Comment: By the way I plan to make additional customization of free jqGrid in the next release. I want to remove *hard corded setting* of jQuery UI classes like `ui-widget`, `ui-widget-header`, `ui-widget-content`, `ui-state-default` from JavaScript code. Instead of that I plan to introduce additional settings like I made for icons and add some callbacks which implements "builder" of elements of jqGrid like headerBuilder and so on. I want to provide Buotstrap customization (close to what you do) out of the box in the next release of free jqGrid.