# How to clear filter value in toolbar if row is removed from advanced search dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid does not clear values in filter toolbar if they are removed from advanced searxh dialog.

To reproduce, open advanced searcg dialog in

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap.htm

and delete both conditons by clicking in minus button
After pressing find button search toolbar still contains those values.
how to fix this ?

[image: still]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you! I didn't thought about the scenario. It's a bug. I posted now [the corresponding fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/effb2accd2d683e5a96ccf3a370f7874b6853d22) to GitHub.

[The demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap1.htm) uses the latest code from GitHub.

Comment: if column in jqgrid is read only and new row is added in andvanced search dialog search field in added row is also read-only. It looks like search field in inherits read-only state from jqgrid column

Comment: I posted this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388700/how-to-specify-value-for-read-only-field-in-advanced-search-dialog