# how to fix exception in filterToolbar in latest free jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Jqgrid filter toolbar is created using

```
$(function () {
    $grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { // this is line myapp.js:797 in stack trace below
        stringResult: true,
        searchOnEnter: true,
        defaultSearch: 'cn'
    });
});
```

Using latest jqgrid from github this causes error in filterToolbar :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
url http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js
lineNumber  8924    column  24
```

How to fix this ?
Stack trace is below.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
    at parseFilter (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:8924:24)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:9255:23)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:384:23)
    at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:136:17)
    at jgrid.extend.filterToolbar (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:8844:16)
    at $.fn.jqGrid (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:2355:14)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/myapp.js:797:15)
    at fire (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:3143:30)
    at Object.self.add [as done] (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:3189:7)
    at jQuery.fn.ready (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:3423:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to make the changes in the code without having an test case. Nevertheless I tried to make [some changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/aca8da0e6490a01520d18b9ed2d2ed16e58aa6d3) near the line 8924 to make it more safer. Please try with the latest sources from the GitHub.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this fixes the issue.